# Why I can't access global variables within a returned function $.post - jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

```
var strTest = '';

$.post(
    'test.php', 
    { post_test : 1 },
    function(data) {
        strTest = data.split('a');

        $.post(
            'test_2.php', 
            { post_test_2 : 2 },
            function(sData) {
                alert(strTest);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

`strTest` - is empty! Why?

Comment: alert data.split('a');  wht is the result ??

Comment: Are you sure that `data.split('a')` returns anything but empty string?

Comment: show us the php code inside `test.php` and `test_2.php`

Comment: What is the `data` returned from your first ajax call?

Comment: @VisioN split will always return an array, never a string. At worst it will return an array with only an empty string in it. OP, alert `typeof(strTest)` instead. If you get "string", the global is being referred to. If you get "object", your code is working, data is just empty.

Comment: @Asad Yep, I meant `data` without `split`. Otherwise, `[""]` is not *empty* by all means. Thanks for correction.

Comment: I was the first one who answered this question but why you assigned the other answer as the correct one? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be working. I have reproduced your case in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJruG/) and as you can see from the resulting alert, `strTest` contains data. The problem probably stems from the fact that `test.php` returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `test.php` because it returns an empty string so `data` is empty and then the `strTest` will be empty because there is nothing in the `data` to be splited!

You should check your code in `test.php`